# 2 Popup instance is shown in MainPage.xaml after navigation back

Tags: windows-phone-7

I  have a popup in Mainpage.xaml click on button popup shows up , but if i navigate to other page and came back to mainpage.xaml and click on same button, 2 popup instance is seen with slight change in UI..Please revert if any solution

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="AddPu">
            <Popup.Child>
                <uc:AddPopup x:Name="ucAdd"></uc:AddPopup>
            </Popup.Child>
        </Popup>
```

Comment: Did you implement any functionality to dispose of the moment on navigation?

Comment: Nope .. is it necessary?, if yes how do we do it in MVVM ??

Comment: Tried disposing it using  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            this.AddPu = null;} No luck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok in figured it out myself :)

```
 <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="AddPu">
            <Popup.Child>
                <uc:AddPopup x:Name="ucAdd"></uc:AddPopup>
            </Popup.Child>
        </Popup>
```

Need to Make IsOpen = always true and before navigating to other page make user control collaps a given below..

```
<Popup IsOpen="True" x:Name="AddPu">--------------Always true here
            <Popup.Child>
                <uc:AddPopup visibility={binding whateverData} x:Name="ucAdd"></uc:AddPopup>
            </Popup.Child>
        </Popup>
```

Comment: Also try not to use <popup> control instead use simple <canvas> panel and make it visibility visible or collapse

Answer (score 0):

In your MainPage constructor there is a line like this:

```
button.Click += ShowPopUpMethod;
```

when you navigetes from main mage run this code:

```
button.Click -= ShowPopUpMethod;
```

Comment: Where do you subscribe on button click? Can you show me the code?

Comment: Am closing the popup before i navigate to other page.But its not working... HideAllPopups(); Uri uri = new Uri(InternalPages.OrderURL, UriKind.Relative); Messenger.Default.Send<Uri>(uri, "Navigate");

Comment: Button comment event is capture in view module as public RelayCommand OrderCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(Order);
            }
        } and Order function have hideAllpopups()

Comment: Try to add more code in your question to help us to reproduce the problem.